# MeteoMatics Weather API

Tags: java, rest

I'm creating an app in Java using REST services to get the weather for a location based on LONG and LAT.
I have successfully been able to retrieve this data, but when I'm using MateoMatics weather API it requires username and password when passed.

How do I pass this in the link?
This is the output:

> MetroMatics API URl: https://api.meteomatics.com/2023-11-22/t_2m:C/53.2293545,-0.5404819/json
> Meteomatics API Response: No username or password provided.

This is my current code:

```
try{
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
        String meteoAPIURl = "https://api.meteomatics.com/"+date +"/"+"t_2m:C"+"/"+latitude +","+longitude+"/"+"json";
        HttpClient meteoMaticsClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest meteoMaticsRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(meteoAPIURl)).build();
        
        System.out.println("MetroMatics API URl: "+meteoAPIURl);
        
        HttpResponse<String>meteoResponse = meteoMaticsClient.send(meteoMaticsRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        String meteomaticsResponseBody = meteoResponse.body();
        
        System.out.println("Meteomatics API Response: " + meteomaticsResponseBody);
    }                  
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need an API key in the form of a username and password, reference: https://www.meteomatics.com/en/weather-api/how-to-get-weather-api-key/

In this article they is a pretty good documentation on how to get a key and how to use it. I consider reading it first and then if you still have issues copy/paste them here.